# Is self-defense breaking the Continental rules?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

In *John Wick*, while resting in his room Wick is attacked by Perkins and he must defend himself.

As stated by Winston:

> no business on Continental grounds.

Does self-defense count as business? Wick grabs his gun and gets information from Perkins, and he is shown to defend himself in his hotel room, however, Winston and John are friends and Winston might bend the rules slightly for John, for example, after being reminded about breaking the rules, Winston gives John Isoef's location at the Red Circle.

In the second film, the rule changes to no blood on Continental grounds, either way self-defense can be covered under the two rules, but is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does self-defense count as business?

## No

Business means exactly that... getting **paid** for killing someone.

Perkins is getting paid for trying to kill John Wick (or at least trying to collect the bounty)... but defending yourself is *entirely different*.

> In the second film, the rule changes to no blood on Continental grounds.

I think this requires interpretation.. "no blood" means "murder"... not "death"/"killing" at least by my understanding.

Self-defence isn't "murder" but is "killing"... assuming that actually happens which, to my recollection, doesn't... So it's moot. I don't believe there are any "self-defence killings" in either movie in the Continental in either movie.

That's not to say that killing (with malice aforethought... and thus "murder") doesn't carry some consequences.

When Wick kills Santino he's breaking the rules in that the Continental gives implicit and explicit *protection* to its guests.

Break that rule and, depending on Winston's mood, the hammer will come down, probably permanently... Or at least, as is extended in Chapter 2, being made "excommunicado", which is effectively the same if there is a bounty out on you.

Comment: Wick killed D'Antonio at the hotel :D. I like this answer. Upvote and check mark. If you don't mind seeing as you know a lot about the movie, I have another question about Wick, but I don't like the current answer, care to weigh in? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87828/why-did-marcus-take-the-contract