# Why would Charon ask John whether he'd need a dinner reservation?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

In the universe of the "John Wick" movies, there's several hotels accross the world, called "The Continental". These hotels, which are mainly (if not exclusively) for hitmen, have several set of rules, including but not limited to:

- Carrying out a contract within the building.
- Fighting or killing someone else within the building.

In the first movie, these rules are the reasons why Ms. Perkins' membership was revoked and her life was forfeited, since she killed someone within the building.

In the second movie, these same rules are the reasons:

- John and Cassian stopped fighting when they rammed through a Continental window during their brawling.
- John got his membership revoked from killing someone.

However, during the first movie, after John told Charon over the phone that he was "dealing with an uninvited guest", the latter asked him whether or not he'd need "a dinner reservation" (hinting to the possibility of killing Ms. Perkins).

Considering that the rules prohibit killing in any way within the hotel, doesn't it mean that Charon would have taken a dinner reservation for 2, had John killed Ms. Perkins?

This question is related to [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87875/is-self-defense-breaking-the-continental-rules). However, the other answer claims that self-defense doesn't count as killing. That doesn't explain why both John and Cassian stopped fighting. John was in a position of self-defense, which, according to the other answer, doesn't break the rules.

Comment: Couldn't "dinner reservation" just mean "body disposal"? It's just a room service option.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, but I was referring to the fact that if John did kill Ms. Perkins, Charon would have to book a dinner reservation for John too.

Comment: Not necessarily...we don't know what "dinner reservation" means. There no specific reason to think it means killing someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question doesn't really make sense.  If it's your life or someone else's, you can absolutely defend yourself.  To do anything contrary would be ridiculous, because that puts you in an "either way you lose" scenario.

John Wick was defending himself, in both instances, against people who were contracted to kill him or were attempting to collect a bounty.  John couldn't be the aggressor against Cassian, as that wasn't allowed.  In turn, he knew Cassian couldn't pursue the hit because that wouldn't be allowed, so they both stopped.

Answer (score 1):

We DO know what a dinner "reservation" is, as John called Charlie and made a reservation for 12 after he was attacked at home. So, when Charon asked John if he needed to make a dinner reservation, he is essentially asking if he needs to dispose of the "uninvited guest's" body.

Self defense is obviously allowed *especially* in the face of preserving The Continental rule of not conducting business on the grounds. And if JW reports an invited guest, Charon is right to assume JW sent them to the hereafter.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this answer, as it does indeed provide interesting information, but it doesn't seem to take into account why both John and Cassian stopped fighting if self defense is allowed.